# Evaluate a simple Python expression

Tags: python

I'm experimentig simple things in python and I have different result when I write the same things in two different ways.

```
(ord(X) + I ^ ord(Y[I])) % 255
```

I want this expression to be equal to for example to 57, since `5 ^ ord(Y[5]) = 114`(with I=5 and Y[I]='w').I thought that since `114+198=312` and `312%255=57` my ord(x) should be 198, but if I write on the python console:

`(ord(chr(198)) +5^ord(Y[5])) % 255` I get 188.

Instead if I write:

`(ord(chr(73)) +5^ord(Y[5])) % 255` I get what I want: 57

Am I missing somethings obvious here?
Why my way of thinking is wrong?

Comment: `(ord(chr(198)+5^ord(Y[5])) % 255` is an invalid Python expression.

Comment: Also you have written exactly the same (invalid) expression twice indicating that you get two different results.

Comment: Sorry I missed one ')'

Comment: `ord(chr(198))` is a complicated way to write `198` - `chr(i)` returns the character with ordinal `i` and `ord(c)` returns the ordinal of character `c`, so `ord(chr(i))` is by definition garanteed to evals to `i`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with a simpler case:

```
>>> 1 + 1 ^ 1
3
```

If you want the XOR to be done first, you need to put parentheses around it, like

```
(ord(X) + (I ^ ord(Y[I]))) % 255
```

Comment: I thought that the xor would be calculated first. That's what I was missing